# Openbox fullscreen alt-tab crashes

Tags: openbox

When there are any, programs run in fullscreen and i alt-tab or spawn new windows it will crash my openbox

[vid](https://youtu.be/wjsOwLpSzJo)

last 2 line in .xsession-errors.old:

```
How are you gentlemen? All your base are belong to us. (Openbox received signal 11)
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

OS: Arch Linux

Kernel: 6.2.6-arch1-1

Thing that I had done:

- Downgrade kernel
- Reinstall kernel
- Reinstall mesa
- Downgrade Openbox
- Reinstall Openbox with all config remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to downgrade `glib2` (2.76.0-1 -> 2.74.6-1). See [the ArchLinux bug database](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/77853) for reference.